# Bootstrap not behaving correctly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, twitter-bootstrap-3, create-react-app

I have React project, which I have generated using `create-react-app`. In the project I want to use Bootstrap.
After project generated there is a file called public/index.html. There I have put the Bootstrap CDNs.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have a component called `ProductListComponent`. Here in render part i have used panel. It is creating the panel but it is not behaving as per the Bootstrap standard.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

class ProductListComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                    <div className="panel panel-primary">
                        <div className="panel-header">
                            <h3>Products</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="panel-body">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ProductListComponent;
```

**Output**
[image]
So can anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's your output html?

Comment: @NielsNet i got the answer. it was cdn issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

you have to add the bootstrap theme

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Theme is optional according to the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Comment: thanx. i got it.  it was cdn issue

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap). Its specifically built to be used to with react. And it is easy too.

or maybe [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) if you're specifically looking at Bootstrap v3

Comment: using `reactstrap` need to follow diffrent syntax for bootstrap

Comment: it was cdn issue. so i got the answer from @Lucaci